# SQL Find all direct descendants in a tree

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a tree in my database that is stored using parent id links.

A sample of what I have for data in the table is:

```
id | name        | parent id
---+-------------+-----------
0  | root        | NULL
1  | Node 1      | 0
2  | Node 2      | 0
3  | Node 1.1    | 1
4  | Node 1.1.1  | 3
5  | Node 1.1.2  | 3
```

Now I would like to get a list of all the direct descendants of a given node but if none exist I would like to have it just return the node itself.

I want the return for the query for children of id = 3 to be:

```
children
--------
4
5
```

Then the query for the children of id = 4 to be:

```
children
--------
4
```

I can change the way I am storing the tree to a nested set but I don't see how that would make the query I want possible.

Comment: I know how to do this using cursors or CTE's, but that is SQL Server .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In new `PostgreSQL 8.4` you can do it with a `CTE`:

```
WITH RECURSIVE q AS
        (
        SELECT  h, 1 AS level, ARRAY[id] AS breadcrumb
        FROM    t_hierarchy h
        WHERE   parent = 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  hi, q.level + 1 AS level, breadcrumb || id
        FROM    q
        JOIN    t_hierarchy hi
        ON      hi.parent = (q.h).id
        )
SELECT  REPEAT('  ', level) || (q.h).id,
        (q.h).parent,
        (q.h).value,
        level,
        breadcrumb::VARCHAR AS path
FROM    q
ORDER BY
        breadcrumb
```

See this article in my blog for details:

- [**`PostgreSQL 8.4`: preserving order for hierarchical query**](http://explainextended.com/2009/07/17/postgresql-8-4-preserving-order-for-hierarchical-query/)

In `8.3` or earlier, you'll have to write a function:

```
CREATE TYPE tp_hierarchy AS (node t_hierarchy, level INT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_hierarchy_connect_by(INT, INT)
RETURNS SETOF tp_hierarchy
AS
$$
        SELECT  CASE
                WHEN node = 1 THEN
                        (t_hierarchy, $2)::tp_hierarchy
                ELSE
                        fn_hierarchy_connect_by((q.t_hierarchy).id, $2 + 1)
                END
        FROM    (
                SELECT  t_hierarchy, node
                FROM    (
                        SELECT  1 AS node
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  2
                        ) nodes,
                        t_hierarchy
                WHERE   parent = $1
                ORDER BY
                        id, node
                ) q;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

and select from this function:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    fn_hierarchy_connect_by(4, 1)
```

The first parameter is the root `id`, the second should be `1`.

See this article in my blog for more detail:

- [**Hierarchical queries in `PostgreSQL`**](http://explainextended.com/2009/05/29/hierarchical-queries-in-postgresql/)

**Update:**

To show only the first level children, or the node itself if the children do not exist, issue this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    t_hierarchy
WHERE   parent = @start
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    t_hierarchy
WHERE   id = @start
        AND NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    t_hierarchy
        WHERE   parent = @start
        )
```

This is more efficient than a `JOIN`, since the second query will take but two index scans at most: the first one to make sure to find out if a child exists, the second one to select the parent row if no children exist.

Comment: The problem with this is I wanted it to show only the first level children and if there weren't any, return only the node itself.  I responded with an answer that works for me after fiddling some more.

Comment: +1 Great answer! I am struggling with exactly this problem at the moment, and would appreciate it if you could just confirm that this is still the way you would approach the problem in the latest PostgreSQL version. Also, ideally I'm looking for a solution that would work in both PosgreSQL and H2

Comment: @JacobusR: the first query is what you should use in 9.2

Comment: Thanks, just to let you know, that I read your blog on this. Absolutely great! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Found a query that works the way I wanted.

```
SELECT * FROM
   ( SELECT id FROM t_tree WHERE name = '' ) AS i,
   t_tree g
WHERE
  ( ( i.id = g.id ) AND 
       NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM t_tree WHERE parentid = i.id ) ) OR
  ( ( i.id = g.parentid ) AND 
       EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM t_tree WHERE parentid = i.id ) )
```